# Is there any command in adb that can damage android phone (without root)?

Tags: android, adb

My question is that is there any chance that any command in adb can damage (both hardware and software) my android phone (**my phone is not rooted**) and if software can it be recovered by factory reset? It is Micromax A120 and runs on android 4.4.2.

Comment: ADB can not damage the hardware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) you can delete and copy data on your mobile phone. So you can loose data or damage the Android System. However you have every time the chance to go into fastboot mode and flash a new Android ROM using the fastboot tools. You only can damage your Android device if you flash a corrupted bootloader using fastboot.

So in short form:

- ADB: You can delete data but you have everytime the chance to recover your system. (However you can loose all your data!)
- Fastboot: You can destroy your Android device if you flash a corrupted bootloader. It's irreparable.

Comment: Can I damage the android system even if my device is not rooted?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is rooted or not. So the answer is yes.

Comment: Will doing a factory reset repair it?

Comment: It depends what you did before. I can not answer this question. However you can flash a new ROM. Then everything should work like before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily mess up your phone if you mess with ADB and don't know what you are doing.  This is particularly true if you are using the 'Recovery' options (flashing new software to your device) in particular, if don't do this correctly, there are opportunities to mess things up (particularly if you are not patient, and don't wait for all operations to complete).

For the most part ADB is just a communication mechanism, and if you are careful to do only things you are confident are safe, there is minimal risk.

Bottom line, there is nothing specific about ADB that is risky, but it is a tool, and if mis-used could cause issues. Use it carefully, and you should be fine.

Comment: Is this possible even if my device is not rooted